# Passing a variable from a Select Value to a document.querySelectorAll(Variable here)

Tags: javascript, variables, selector

I want to be able to select a value from a Selector dropdown on an HTML page and have the 'Value' passed to the document.querySelectorAll() on the .js page. Tried many different variations and it's just not happening.

```
<div class="custom-select">
     <select id="selected" onchange="changeKey()">
            <option value="0">Select Key:</option>
            <option value="aminorpenta">A</option>
     </select>
</div>




Var aminorpenta = [".ANat",".CNat",".DNat",".ENat",".GNat"];

function changeKey() {
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll(variable goes here), i;
 for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
 elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
 elements[i].style.color = "black";
alert(dayVal);
 }
}
```

Comment: What's `dayVal` ? I don't see it used anywhere else. Also, do you plan on having multiple selects or just one specific?

Comment: You can `stringify` the content of `aminorpenta`. Assuming _every_ option has an attribute that follows the same convention, you can parse the attribute of the selected option. Is that something like what you are trying to do?

Comment: If I use the variable directly into the document.querySelectorAll(variable here) it works as desired.

Comment: @MihailMinkov sorry about that, dayVal leftovers from a different try. And yes, there will be mulitple selections/variables, 12 in all.

Comment: So just to make it clear, you have 12 `select` elements and you want to update their options using arrays with strings?

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky I'm really new to this so some of those terms I'm not all familiar with, sorry.

Comment: @MihailMinkov The value inside the option for the select will be the name of a variable. When the selection is made, onchange, the variable will pass to the query all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map of values in standard Javascript object notation.
You can retreive values from an object using a dynamic key by using square bracket notation.

```
const myObject = {
    aminorpenta: [".ANat",".CNat",".DNat",".ENat",".GNat"],
    //  more key: value pairs
}
function changeKey() {
    const selectElement = document.getElementById("selected");
    const selectedValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(myObject[selectedValue])
    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        elements[i].style.color = "black";
    }
}
```

Edited.

Comment: Very welcome! Can I trouble you to accept the answer...?